# OOM: Drawing a 3MB .png file on a canvas

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a Bitmap (as a background) on the SurfaceView's Canvas

I tried:

```
Drawable bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(surfaceView.getContext(), R.drawable.bg);
bg.draw(canvas);
```

and then I tried:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = (int) (1600 / width);  //since the width of the image is 1600px
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(surfaceView.getResources(), R.drawable.bg, options);
```

and both result in the same OOM Exception

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 147456012 byte allocation
with 1048576 free bytes and 95MB until OOM
```

I would appreciate some help on how to draw my .png image which is 3MB (1600*2560)

Comment: please read this: Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I read it before posting my question. Thus, I used options.inSampleSize

Comment: `... my .png image which is 3MB (1600*2560)`, **NO, it's over 16MB**. To be exact, **16.384.000 bytes** (1600*2560*4 bytes).

Comment: The file inside the drawable folder is 3153KB ...

Comment: `The file inside the drawable folder is 3153KB` but once **deflated in memory**, it's over 16MB. 3MB is the file size **on disk**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why 3MB couldn't be initially loaded on the heap without OOM

But Adding the large heap line to the Manifest solved the problem

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...>
```

Hope it'll help someone who'd face the same problem :)

Comment: You could use a proper image loading library like Glide or Fresco also.

Comment: Would using it to load just one image is worth it ? the only "big" image I have is this one for the background..

Comment: If you only have that one image to load in your whole app, probably not worth it.

Comment: You are right, even this one is still too slow to load and it slows the app significantly, I only used it as an alternative to a linear gradient (banding problems)... so I guess even sacrificing performance for this background is not worth it.

Comment: It's over 16MB, not 3MB. 3MB is only the **file size** on disk.